# Masking a string in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, hybrid

I want to mask a string in Ionic-4, the format of the string will be 1234567890987. I want output as 123xxxxxxx987 (i.e) first 3 characters and last 3 characters should be plain and remaining all characters should be masked. Please let me know, how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a function `replaceAt` as like this -

```js
function replaceAt(str, pos, value){
    var arr = str.split('');
    arr[pos]=value;
    return arr.join('');
}

var s = "1234567890987";
for(var i=3;i<s.length-3;i++) s = replaceAt(s, i, 'x');
console.log(s);
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
const number:string = "123456789";

const hideMiddleString = (text: string): string => {
  if(text.length <= 6) {
    return text;
  }
  const beginString = text.substr(0, 3); // Take 3first chars
  const endString = text.substr(-3); // take 3 last chars
  // x.repeat will create string of xxxx base on string length - 3 first chars - 3 last chars
  return beginString + "x".repeat(text.length - 6) + endString;
};

console.log(hideMiddleString(number));
```

[live sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-wdqtw3)